# How to compare two comma-separated lists and removing matching values using XSLT 1.0

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I have two variables which contain comma separated values:-

```
  <xsl:variable name="Include-Cities" select="'London, Paris, Washington, Tokyo'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Exclude-Cities" select="'Paris, Tokyo'"/>
```

I have a requirement to remove the values in `$Include-Cities` which match those found in `$Exclude-Cities`, so in a way I am subtracting those values from the `$Include-Cities` variable and outputting the result.

I have looked around the web and found the following example which provides search and replace functionality and which works if the order of the cities in $Exclude-Cities matches the order in $Include-Cities, but fails if the order of values if different.

I am stuck as the values in both lists can change daily and i will never know what those values are, therefore i don't think performing a sort (if its possible) will work.

The example i found:-

```
<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then i call the template using:-

```
<xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$Include-Cities"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$Exclude-Cities" />
    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="''"/>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

I have also looked at examples of tokenizing the values and comparing that way but have had no joy whatsoever.

I know there are string comparsion functions available in 2.0 but I am restricted to using XSLT 1.0.

I am an XSLT noob so can anyone help please?

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: "*I am restricted to using XSLT 1.0.*" Which specific XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: Hi @michael, i am currently using libxslt via xsltproc

Comment: Good, then my answer should work for you as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have also looked at examples of tokenizing the values and comparing
>   that way but have had no joy whatsoever.

Tokenizing *is* the correct approach to take here. If your processor supports the EXSLT `str:tokenize` extension function, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="Include-Cities" select="'London, Paris, Washington, Tokyo'"/>
<xsl:variable name="Exclude-Cities" select="'Paris, Tokyo'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="incl" select="str:tokenize($Include-Cities, ', ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="excl" select="str:tokenize($Exclude-Cities, ', ')"/>
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$incl[not(.=$excl)]"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

and get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <token>London</token>
  <token>Washington</token>
</output>
```

Otherwise you would have to use a recursive named template to do tokenizing, convert the results to node-sets and then do the comparison as shown above.

Comment: huge thank you, much appreciated. i have just tried your method using the EXSLT function and it works like a charm. Just what i was looking for, been bashing my head with this for last few days so thank you again